# Difference between "an" and "auf" in the example provided

Tags: standard-german

Duden provides the folowing definition of *auf*:

> zur Angabe der Richtung; bezieht sich auf eine Stelle, Oberfläche, auf einen Erstreckungsbereich, einen Zielpunkt o. Ä., bezeichnet den Gang zu einem/in einen Raum, zu einem/in ein Gebäude; gibt die Richtung in einem Seins-, Tätigkeitsbereich o. Ä. an

Why, then, is the following sentence an example of *an* rather than *auf*?

> *an* eine andere Dienststelle versetzt werden

It seems like *auf* would fit the example better?

Comment: What is your source for this example? In [Duden online](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/auf_Praeposition#Bedeutung1b) I can't find your example.

Comment: @IQV The example is from the “an” page on Duden but I was wondering why it wasn’t “auf”

Answer (score 2):

There is no special explanation for this. It is simply used this way.

For *Stelle* in the meaning of *occupation*, *appointment*, *job position*, etc., but also sometimes for the other meanings like *location*, it is expressed this way and not using **auf**.

It is *an eine Stelle versetzt werden*, and not *auf eine Stelle versetzt werden*, etc.

In the other meanings (*Platz*, *Ort*, i.e. location, position), *auf* kann be used too, but there is also a third possibility, e.g. *zur Stelle sein* (to be present).

You'll simply have to learn these things by, er... doing.

Comment: Both *an* and *auf* are possible for the occupation context. This seems to depend on the region, though.

Comment: Is there a reason the definition of “auf” includes “auf eine Stelle”? Is it used differently?

Comment: *Auf eine Stelle* is usually a different meaning of *Stelle*, i.e. location, position. But, as others said, this may differ from region to region and probably also from other things (subculture, etc.).

Comment: In other words: *Stelle* has many different but somehow related meanings. Sometimes, "an" sounds more appropriate, sometimes other prepositions (*auf*, *zu*, *in*) are "better". I personally find "Sie ist auf eine andere Dienststelle versetzt" sound weird. Others may find it natural. But note that it is *anstelle von* (in lieu, instead), and not *aufstelle von*.

Comment: Warum das so oder so ist, das steht *an anderer Stelle* <- that does really never take *auf*; vice versa *auf einem anderen Blatt*. It's possible, in my humble opinion, that the initial syllable of "*an*-der-er" facilitates use of the prep. *an*, but *Stelle*, viz *aufstellen*, tends to *auf* instead!? *auf* is illogical, strictly speaking, because we work *an etwas*. Even, the multi-way mismatch between En. *on*, *up*, and Ger. *an*, *auf* ... shows that it's not strict nor easy, historically.

Comment: As I said: these things should be learned.

Answer (score 2):

I see no pattern. If there is one *at all*, it's about avoiding ambiguity.

> Sie wurde an die Pestalozzischule versetzt.

This is clearly about the occupation, because talking about putting a person next a building makes little sense.

> Sie wurde auf die Pestalozzischule versetzt.

Same, we aren't talking about putting someone on the roof. It must be about the occupation.

> Sie wurde in die Pestalozzischule versetzt.

This may be about the occupation, but it may also mean she's put into the school in her mind, because *versetzen* may also mean *consider, dream*:

> Versetz dich doch mal in ihre Lage!

Comment: Would “an” and “auf” be synonymous in this context? Is there a reason you would opt for one over the other?

Comment: I live at the border between lower and upper German and I see no difference. Casually I would use *auf* and I think people further north agree. For written texts I would use *an*, because that sounds upper German and thus "more correct".

Answer (score 1):

Im also learning german. Might be wrong but..
"An" logically means position of being next to things (sticked). You stand next to kiosk (little shop), you stand next to "schalter" (which is window that you are provided with service). But it gets little bit weird when its not physical position but rather imaginary one. Its like putting chess knights next to box or "office"
another example is that anstellen means employ
and angestellt means employed
and therefore Angestellter means cleric or employee. Try to imagine that you are putting that employee to next to office. Also i think they are lot of words that require specific preposition like auf, an or so, even though there is no exact reason

Comment: *an* means many different things in different contexts. Certainly, *next to* is frequently *neben*. One could think it relates to *an* (due to the n), but that's a different topic. You basically have an *a* and a kind of morphemic inflection *n* that escapes analysis to a large degree. Compare *Angabe*, *Anfang*, *Antrag* or whatever.